# Internet Explorer / jQuery / Javascript issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

For some odd reason Internet Explorer won't run my queries properly.
I designed this web application on Firefox, everything runs smooth over there, the only problem is in Internet Explorer. I have a Perl script which inserts status messages into a table called `tbl_messages`. Since the Perl script is being handled by an Ajax call, you won't see a thing of that. Now where it goes wrong is after the first message, it does update 'gezien' to 1, but yet it seems to show the same message over and over again.

This is the status page

```
include('actions/classes.php');
mysql_select_db('st_beheer');
$dbres      = mysql_query("SELECT id, message FROM tbl_messages WHERE uniekid=".$_GET['uniekid']." AND `gezien` = 0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1") OR DIE (mysql_error());
$message    = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbres);
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_messages SET gezien = '1' WHERE id='".$message['id']."'") OR DIE (mysql_error());
echo var_dump($message);
```

And over here the ajax calls

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var post = $('#f_export').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "export.pl",
          data: post
        });

        var timer = setInterval(StatusUpdate, 1000); 
        var uniekid = $('#uniekid').val();

        function StatusUpdate() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "status.php?uniekid="+uniekid,
              success: function(data){
                $('#progressie').append(data);
              }
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Mozilla (working) vardump:

> Import proces gestart... 
>   array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "27" ["message"]=> string(45)
>   "Controleren of de database naam al bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=>
>   string(2) "28" ["message"]=> string(58) "Database met de naam
>   stuftax_asdasdasdasd is aangemaakt..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2)
>   "29" ["message"]=> string(28) "Rechten worden bijgewerkt..." }
>   array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "30" ["message"]=> string(34) "ST20 bron
>   tabel word aangemaakt..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31"
>   ["message"]=> string(46) "Een verbinding maken met de nieuwe
>   database..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "32" ["message"]=>
>   string(31) "Import specificatie oproepen..." } bool(false) bool(false)
>   bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
>   bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) array(2) { ["id"]=>
>   string(2) "33" ["message"]=> string(35) "Tabellen aanmaken in de
>   database..." } bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
>   bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
>   bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
>   bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
>   bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) array(2) { ["id"]=>
>   string(2) "34" ["message"]=> string(40) "Tabellen aanpassen, sleutels
>   aanmaken..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "35" ["message"]=>
>   string(35) "Poging doen om bestand te openen..." } array(2) { ["id"]=>
>   string(2) "36" ["message"]=> string(108) "Bestand
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/projecten/Examen/files/delano_test_username_08112011_133230.asc
>   succesvol geopend..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "37"
>   ["message"]=> string(23) "Bestand is ingelezen..." } array(2) {
>   ["id"]=> string(2) "38" ["message"]=> string(31) "Regels verwerken in
>   tabellen..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "39" ["message"]=>
>   string(28) "Import procedure afgerond..." }

And over here the Internet Explorer one

> Import proces gestart... array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
>   ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al
>   bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=>
>   string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al bestaat..." } array(2)
>   { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de
>   database naam al bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
>   ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al
>   bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=>
>   string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al bestaat..." } array(2)
>   { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de
>   database naam al bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
>   ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al
>   bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=>
>   string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al bestaat..." } array(2)
>   { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de
>   database naam al bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
>   ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al
>   bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=>
>   string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al bestaat..." } array(2)
>   { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de
>   database naam al bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
>   ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al
>   bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=>
>   string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al bestaat..." } array(2)
>   { ["id"]=> string(2) "40" ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de
>   database naam al bestaat..." } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
>   ["message"]=> string(45) "Controleren of de database naam al
>   bestaat..." }

Comment: Shouldnt it return empty the second time, since it changes `gezien` to 1, and only selects it if its 0. Also REMEMBER to remove cache from calls, if you send the same parameters, IE will use a cached version - therefore giving you the same result.

Comment: How do i remove the chache from my calls, because that is currently my problem i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your Ajax call include cache: false property

```
function StatusUpdate() { 
        $.ajax({ 
          url: "status.php?uniekid="+uniekid, 
          cache:false,
          success: function(data){ 
            $('#progressie').append(data); 
          } 
        }); 
    };
```